# spring-boot launch-script: how to avoid pid_folder identity-subdirectory?

Tags: spring-boot, pid, launch, init.d

We are using spring-boot with the embedded launcher-script in `service` mode, to have daemonized/init.d behavior.

We however do not have an `/etc/init.d` symlink to the spring-boot jar as that would require using `sudo`. we avoid `sudo` to pass a profile-environmental like `-Dspring.profiles.active=$APP_PROFILE` in the `JAVA_OPTS`
(this won't work when started via `sudo` but defined in `/home/appuser/.bashrc` (?) )

We have this directory-layout with some indirections. basically `app.jar => current/app.jar => build-xx/app.jar`

```
appuser@host:~/apps/services$ ls
app.jar -> /home/appuser/apps/services/current/services-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
current -> /home/appuser/apps/services/services-1298
services-1298
```

When starting the application with `app.jar start` the launch-script generates an additional pid-subdirectory in the pid-folder based on the "identity" of the program. For us this can look like this:

```
/home/appuser/apps/services/run/services-1.0-SNAPSHOT_homeappuserappsservicesservices-1298/services.pid
```

Unlike when used with an symlinked `/etc/init.d` which gets special treatment and the pid-subdir `services-1.0-SNAPSHOT_homeappuserappsservicesservices-1298` is omitted/stays stable.

This dynamic pid-subdir makes it very hard for us to check the daemon's status or start/stop during deployment because you have to always get the sequence right and nobody is stopping you from starting a process twice (the old instance and now a new instance with a new identity-subdir).

So, does anyone know why this pid-subdir-identity stuff must exist and what would be our best way to deal with it?
Do we have a bad setup?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the identity by using the `APP_NAME` environment variable.

I'd recommend configuring your service's environment variables using a `.conf` file next to the jar file. For example, if your app is called `app.jar`, you conf file should be named `app.conf` and be placed in the same directory as the jar. You can then configure `APP_NAME` and `JAVA_OPTS` etc for your application. This should allow you to use `init.d` if you so wish.

Comment: we are using `.conf` and tried working with the `APP_NAME` but it's only possible to set `APP_NAME` as an environmental and we have several different apps unser `/home/appuser/apps/...` like backend, frontend, api etc. - this does only work with one app per user isn't it?

Comment: No. If you use a .conf file as I recommended in my answer you can configure the environment on a per-application basis irrespective of how many users are involved

Comment: this won't work, APP_NAME is not configurable via a conf file entry but only via an environmental variable. it's even used before the conf file is sourced

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I can't think of any reason for that to be the case. Please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) and we can take a look at changing it. You could also fix it yourself by using a [custom launch script](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-script-customization).

Comment: misleading comment, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html